# Can a player move the ball through the pitch while holding it tightly near his body in football?

Tags: rules, football

I was wondering whether in football one can move the ball through the pitch in an unconventional way, namely by holding it:

- on his forehead
- between his head and shoulder
- between calf and thigh while jumping towards the goal by one foot

Are these things allowed?

Comment: It's not an exact match, but I believe my answer there already covers the salient points raised in this question and therefore is close enough to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think - without scanning the rules myself - that gdrt's reply hits the target: those "tricks" are not effective, so there is no need to exclude them.

My contribution is twofold:

One, if someone found a clever trick allowing to "carry" the ball, just about as easy as carrying it by hand, it almost surely would soon be forbidden in the rules. The spirit of the sport is quite clear, you do not carry the ball (that would be rugby-like, and they split long ago).

Two, *some* tricks are allowed. Namely, Cuauhtemoc Blanco's jump with the ball between his feet. [(see at YouTube - 1 minute)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5SB-L8jpbs) But, there it is, it is not something you would do more than one hop, surely not all the way down the field...